# turtlebot4 nav2: how to call action navigateToPose from node in cpp

Tags: ros2, c++, nav2, turtlebot4

I am migrating a node that send goals to nav2 (originally move_base) thru an action since I need to know if it has been reached or cancelled by the planner.

It will work with the Turtlebot4. I've been reading the nav2 documentation and launching the nav2 launch of Turtlebot4 and I guess that I need to call the action `/navigate_to_pose` of the node `bt_navigator`. However showing the interface, I see that the result is a `std_msgs/Empty`.

How can I easily send goals to Turtlebot4 from a cpp node and know the status of the navigation (i.e. goal reached/cancelled/travelling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [example](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/humble/rclcpp/actions/minimal_action_client/member_functions.cpp) and I realized that the class `rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<T>::WrappedResult` already has the attribute `code` (that can be either `rclcpp_action::ResultCode::SUCCEEDED` , `rclcpp_action::ResultCode::ABORTED` or `rclcpp_action::ResultCode::CANCELLED`) so there is no need of putting this information in the action interface.